# Why does 'chop' not work with <STDIN>?

Tags: perl

I am trying to figure out why the chop function is not working for me when I try to take input from the user:

```
my $string = <STDIN>;
my $chr = chop($string);
print "String: $string\n";
print "Char: $chr\n";
```

output

```
perl chop.pl
hello
String: hello
Char:
```

But if I use a string, then it works!

```
my $string = "frong";
my $chr = chop($string);
print "String: $string\n";
print "Char: $chr\n";
```

output
[583]

```
perl chop.pl
String: fron
Char: g
```

Comment: A very good module for debugging output is `Data::Dumper`. Try this: `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper $chr;`. You will see `$VAR1 = "\n"`.

Comment: Btw, I like your name. I started `Learning Perl` from this book only. :)

Comment: @TLP do i need to install modules separately or are they included in perl?(my perl version is 5.8.8 which gives me error Global symbol "$chr" requires explicit package name at chop.pl line 6.
Execution of chop.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
)

Comment: @RohitJain oh!i didnt know there exists a book named learning perl:|thank you for increasing my resources.

Comment: Have you declared your `$chr` using `my $chr` for the first time. It is required if you are using `use strict` in your file.

Comment: @learningperl. Post your code, where you are getting this error.

Comment: use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
 print Dumper $chr; 
my $string = <STDIN>;
  my $chr = chop($string);
  print "String: $string\n";
  print "Char: $chr\n";

Comment: You have printed your `$chr` before declaring it.. `print Dumper $chr;` move this statement after chopping. `my $chr = chop($string);`

Comment: @learningperl Data::Dumper is a core module since perl 5.005. And you called `$chr` before declaring it.

Comment: @learningperl you can also [edit] your posts if you want to add code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass input from console, `chop` is chopping the `newline` that is at the end of the string, which is present when you hit `Enter`. While your string does not contain that.

Comment: then how do i chop a string input from the user?

Comment: Well, do you want to remove the last character only? then just use `chop` twice.

Comment: @learningperl Or you could use `chomp` and then `chop`. `chomp` is more appropriate for removing newlines.

Comment: thank you! how do i chop a random character from a string?say character number 3?

Comment: @learningperl. What do you exactly want to do. `chop` is used to just remove the last character from the string.

Comment: to remove the third character from a string, use `$chr = substr($string, 2, 1, '')`  (will die if the string is not long enough)

Comment: `chop` removes the last character from a string. `chomp` removes the last character, but only if it's a newline; it's useful more often than `chomp` is. (Before `chomp` was introduced, it was common to use `chop` with the *assumption* that the character being removed would be a newline.) There are no specialized functions to remove single characters in other ways. `perldoc -f chop` and `perldoc -f chomp`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're chop()'ing is the newline at the end of the string. To remove the newline upon assignment from STDIN:

```
chomp(my $string = <STDIN>);
```

In other words, your program should look like this:

```
chomp(my $string = <STDIN>);
my $chr = chop($string);
print "String: $string\n";
print "Char: $chr\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the perl documentation for these two functions `chop` and `chomp` might just do.

`chomp`

> chomp   This safer version of "chop" removes any trailing string that
>               corresponds to the current value of $/ (also known as
>               $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR in the "English" module.

`chop`

> chop    Chops off the last character of a string and returns the
>               character chopped.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

If you're printing diagnostics to show variable contents, put some form of delimiter around them, then you'd see the newline in your $chr example.

eg.

```
print "String: \"$string\"\n";
print "Char: \"$chr\"\n";
```